# Passay generate password that is not an old one

Tags: java, passwords

I know that is possible to validate a password with passay that makes sure the validated one is not one of a given list of old passwords

`passwordData.setPasswordReferences(..)`

I see that password generation method only requires CharacterRule objects, so I was wondering if there is a way to make sure the generated password is not an old one, even though the odds are pretty low I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't seem to be possible, the CharacterRules only allow inclusion, not exclusion.
You might want to validate the generated pw and retry.